# XML Deserialization encoding issue

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I already searched a lot and unable to find a solution and unable to determine the correct approach

I am serializing an object to xml string and deserializing it back to an object using c#. XML string after serialization adds a leading ?. When I dezerialize it back to the object I am getting an error There is an error in XML document (1, 1)

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

Serialization code:

```
 string xmlString = null;
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
 XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
 ns.Add("abc", "http://example.com/abc/");
 XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream,Encoding.Unicode);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj, ns);
 memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
 xmlString = ConvertByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

ConvertByteArrayToString:

```
   UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    string constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);
```

Deserialization Code:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
object obj = ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
stringReader.Close();
return (T)obj;
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong with encoding and I need a solution that works for most cases. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use following function for serialization and Deserialization

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T dataToSerialize)
{
    try
    {
        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText)
{
    try
    {
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized XML contains a [Unicode byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning, and this is where the deserializer fails.

To remove the BOM you need to create a different version of encoding suppressing BOM instead of using default `Encoding.Unicode`:

```
new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, new UnicodeEncoding(false, false))
```

Here the second `false` prevents BOM being prepended to the string.